# PIC12F675 ADC not working properly

Tags: pic, analog, adc, c, embedded

I wrote a code that takes an analog input from a potentiometer and controls the frequency of a clock pulse. So, the idea is to increase the frequency when I increase the pot and decrease the frequency when I decrease the pot. It should change at a constant rate.

## The problem:

When I change the pot, the frequency changes, but not in a constant rate. For example, when I increase the pot, the frequency may decrease and if I increase the pot more, it may increase again. And so on.

Here are some examples of when I keep **ONLY INCREASING** the pot:
[image]
[image]
[image]

## The Config:

```
#pragma config FOSC = INTRCCLK  
#pragma config WDTE = OFF       
#pragma config PWRTE = OFF      
#pragma config MCLRE = OFF       
#pragma config BOREN = ON       
#pragma config CP = OFF         
#pragma config CPD = OFF
```

## The Code:

```
#include <xc.h>
#include "config.h"
#define _XTAL_FREQ 4000000

void delay(unsigned char freq){
    for(int i = 0; i < (int)freq; i++){
        __delay_ms(1);
    }
}

void dClock(unsigned char freq){
    GPIO1 = 1;
    delay(freq);
    GPIO1 = 0;
    delay(freq);
}

void InitADC(){
    ANSEL = 0x11;
    ADCON0 = 0b00000001;
    CMCON = 0x7;
    VRCON = 0;
}

unsigned char GetADCValue(){
    ADCON0 = 0b00000011;
    while(GO_nDONE);
    return ADRESL;
}

void main(void) {
    TRISIO0 = 1; //analog input
    TRISIO1 = 0; //output
    TRISIO2 = 0;
    TRISIO3 = 1; //mode
    TRISIO5 = 1; //pulse_button

    char pressed = 0;
    GPIO1 = 0;

    InitADC();

    while(1){
        if(GPIO3 == 0){
            GPIO2 = 1;
            unsigned char freq = GetADCValue();
            dClock(freq);
        }
        else{
            GPIO2 = 0;
            if(GPIO5 == 1 && pressed == 0){
                GPIO1 = 1;
                __delay_ms(500);
                GPIO1 = 0;
                pressed = 1;
            }
            else if(GPIO5 == 0 && pressed == 1){
                pressed = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Other than that, everything works fine. Could someone help me with that?
Thank you.

Comment: Please share the datasheet of your potentiometer. Note that only ideal potetiometers have an ideal linear relationship.

Comment: Measure the adc input with a multimeter and scope (both) and verify whether it corresponds to the frequency you measure on the scope.

Comment: @Huisman The whole circuit is made on proteus simulation, including the pot. So, the pot shouldn't be faulty.

Comment: I have no experience with proteus, but the word simulation suggest it would even easier to deduce. Write down the values of the ADC and the frequency and try to identify whether there is a pattern.

Comment: What's ```CMCON = 0x7;``` doing in the ADCinit() ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ADC is only returning the least significant bits with `return ADRESL;`.
So, if the pot was in such position the returned ADC value was 0b011, "increasing the pot" will return 0b000 as next step.

[image]

You should either `return ADRESH;` or set `ADCON0 = 0b**1**0000001;` or change freq to an unsigned int and `return (ADRESH<8) & ADRESL`

Comment: Yes that's it!! It was overflowing as you said. Thank you so much.